# OpenGL Uniform Functions - Why so many?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, uniform

Why are there so many functions to set Uniforms?

```
glUniform1f    glUniform2f    glUniform3f    glUniform4f
glUniform1fv   glUniform2fv   glUniform3fv   glUniform4fv
glUniform1i    glUniform2i    glUniform3i    glUniform4i
glUniform1iv   glUniform2iv   glUniform3iv   glUniform4iv
glUniform1ui   glUniform2ui   glUniform3ui   glUniform4ui
glUniform1uiv  glUniform2uiv  glUniform3uiv  glUniform4uiv

glUniformMatrix2fv  glUniformMatrix2x3fv  glUniformMatrix2x4fv
glUniformMatrix3fv  glUniformMatrix3x2fv  glUniformMatrix3x4fv
glUniformMatrix4fv  glUniformMatrix4x2fv  glUniformMatrix4x3fv
```

I think the way Data is uploaded to the vertex and element buffers is waaay better, since i don't have to call a different function for a different type. 
Why is this the case with uniforms? Is there a possibility to use just one function, where i can just pass a pointer?

Comment: Because C does not support function overloading.

Comment: @LogicStuff I think OP is asking why it's not something like `glUniform_(location, GL_FVEC4, 1, pointer)`, but `glUniform4fv(location, 1, pointer)` instead. Function overloading is not needed to implement this.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat exactly!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: But it *has that function*. `glUniform4fv` can do exactly what you did. It just takes one more value: an array count, which must be 1 for non-array types (or arrays of length 1). So it's rather unclear what the OP is complaining about.

Comment: @NicolBolas: that there isn't just one `glUniform(GLint location, GLenum datatype, GLsizei count, const GLvoid *data)` call that does "the right thing" based on `datatype`. So if you want to load an array of two vec4 you could do something like `glUniform(loc, GL_FLOAT_VEC4, 2, ptr);` (where `ptr` points to 8 floats).

Comment: @peppe: Have we reached "peak function"? Are we so running out of functions that we need to start conserving them? Personally, I like having the choice between using an array and using function parameters.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I totally agree. `void *` => bad and evil. Cf. my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Hindsight is always 20/20 and the choice was done to be in line with other functions that take vectorial data in various types and dimensionality. I'm referring to glVertex… of course. Now the initial reason for pass by value was, that on some architectures there are enough registers around that this is more efficient to pass by value in register. Also compilers could optimize preceding operations to end up the right values in the right register.

OpenGL is a descendant of IrixGL developed by SGI for their graphics workstations and the Irix OS. These workstations used the MIPS architecture. And the calling convention for MIPS is (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS)

> The most commonly used[5] calling convention for 32 bit MIPS is the O32[6] ABI which passes the first four arguments to a function in the registers $a0-$a3; …
>
> …
>
> The N32 and N64 ABIs pass the first eight arguments to a function in the registers $a0-$a7; …

So there you have it: On MIPS it's actually a quite sensible choice to pass vec4 elements per value. Especially in IrixGL and OpenGL-1.0 where there were no vertex arrays and you'd have to make lots of glVertex calls.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using modern OpenGL, you can use [Uniform Buffer Objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object), which have been available since OpenGL 3.1.

However, there is a little more involved "setup" required. Specifically, they require that you author your shaders in a particular way (defining the uniform blocks). You will also either need to define a memory layout (`std140` is a popular one) for the blocks, or, alternatively query the layouts, to determine how your uniform buffer data should be formatted, so that the binding matches the format expected by the GPU.

After all the setup has been done, the binding is done with a call to: `glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, <name>)`, just like vertex and index streams.

Comment: This seems like a possible solution, that might be more efficient then iterating through about 20 if-Statements. I will have a look into it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This was noted during the discussion of [GL_ARB_shader_objects](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/shader_objects.txt):

> 15) There is the potential for a huge explosion of load uniform
>       commands, what to do?
>
> DISCUSSION: We need to be able to load a vec1, vec2, vec3, or vec4, or
>   arrays of vec1, arrays of vec2, arrays of vec3 or arrays of vec4.
>   Furtheremore, there is a need to also load 2x2, 3x3 and 4x4 matrices,
>   and arrays of 2x2, arrays of 3x3 and arrays of 4x4 matrices. The input
>   values to the load uniforms commands can (traditional OpenGL) come in
>   bytes, shorts, ints, floats, doubles and unsigned bytes, unsigned shorts
>   and unsigned ints.
>
> RESOLUTION: A suggested subset is in the New Procedures and Functions
>   section below.

The subset in question is the one that got ratified:

```
void Uniform1fARB(int location, float v0)
void Uniform2fARB(int location, float v0, float v1)
void Uniform3fARB(int location, float v0, float v1, float v2)
void Uniform4fARB(int location, float v0, float v1, float v2, float v3)

void Uniform1iARB(int location, int v0)
void Uniform2iARB(int location, int v0, int v1)
void Uniform3iARB(int location, int v0, int v1, int v2)
void Uniform4iARB(int location, int v0, int v1, int v2, int v3)

void Uniform1fvARB(int location, sizei count, const float *value)
void Uniform2fvARB(int location, sizei count, const float *value)
void Uniform3fvARB(int location, sizei count, const float *value)
void Uniform4fvARB(int location, sizei count, const float *value)

void Uniform1ivARB(int location, sizei count, const int *value)
void Uniform2ivARB(int location, sizei count, const int *value)
void Uniform3ivARB(int location, sizei count, const int *value)
void Uniform4ivARB(int location, sizei count, const int *value)

void UniformMatrix2fvARB(int location, sizei count, boolean transpose, const float *value)
void UniformMatrix3fvARB(int location, sizei count, boolean transpose, const float *value)
void UniformMatrix4fvARB(int location, sizei count, boolean transpose, const float *value)
```

The calls for unsigned integers and non-square matrices got added later.

I think @datenwolf is on point with the remark that the `glVertex` family of calls had many functions in order to optimize the pass by value in registers, on the other hand setting uniforms is supposed to happen various orders of magnitude less often than passing vertices, so I don't think that performance here is a real issue.

"Follow the already established API" sounds like a more sensible explaination.

---

Besides, do you really like passing data types through `void *` interfaces? What you're asking is an API like

```
glUniform(GLint location, GLenum datatype, GLsizei count, const GLvoid *data)
```

GL is already full of such levels of brokeness and type-unsafety (hello, untyped `GLenum`s!), I'd rather much prefer APIs that do not add more of that.

Comment: I prefer the type of API you mentioned at the end. Less functions to memorize, i can have all the uniforms for my next drawcall set in one buffer and i don't have to associate the type with the function (less if statements)

Comment: "Less functions to memorize" is a non-problem. Having compile-time errors instead of runtime (silent) errors that nobody is going to check via glGetError, and the relative costs of checking that the parameters you pass make sense, is surely bigger. If you want less functions, use C++ and overloads?

Answer (score 0):

What the hardware needs to do depending on the uniform data format might be different.

What you're asking is that the potential switch/if series are implemented within the GL driver. You'd then have to pay for that cost for every use of the API, even if the application already knew exactly what type of uniform it was about to set. This would not be an efficient API design (regardless of the fact that actually passing a buffer of uniforms is way more efficient these days. That wasn't the case when that API was designed).

That was the reason why glVertex3f et al. had that API design too. But at least those didn't generate glErrors. It's a bit flimsier for Uniforms as they definitely generate errors, so the code can't really be fully minimal.